# dll is being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating an extension in Visual Studio 2012 and keep having this error which is getting rather frustrating. [image]

The way I have dealing with it recently is that I have to go into the add-in manager before I start the extension, un-check all boxes for the add-in, close out of Visual Studio, reopen Visual Studio, start the add-in debug, re-check the add-in in the add-in manager, then restart the debuging. As you can imagine this is rather time consuming and is annoying. It also only works about 70% of the time. It occurs also when I try to build or rebuild the project and no other Visual Studios are running. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening or is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: In addition, if I relentlessly try to build the project over and over again, it will eventually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're discovering, you shouldn't install an extension from the bin folder while you work on it.

Remove the extension entirely from your main copy of VS, then create a separate test environment by running `devenv /rootsuffix MyTest` and install the extension there.

You should then debug the extension from that instance and kill it when you're done.

Comment: And even better: stop using Add-ins and use extensions if at all possible.